# Can I permanently enable Camera Mode?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

Camera Mode is a new option in the Saints Row series that I'd like to have always on. Sometimes I run across something that happens quickly that I'd love to get a screencap of, but then I find that the Camera Mode has been disabled again.

I never manually disable Camera Mode. It seems to turn off automatically, and I can't really figure out the pattern of *why* it does. Is there any way to permanently enable Camera Mode so I don't have to keep going to my phone in game and turning it on again?

I'm playing the Xbox 360 version, so I have no other way to quickly and easily screencap images.

Comment: I can't even tell when it turns off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand how frustrating this must be as my research has indicated that the game turns it off quite frequently without warning or indication. You're not alone in your question as saintsrow.com's forum has [a thread](http://saintsrow.com/community/go/thread/view/136781/28748607/?pg=last) full of users with the same concerns. From the responses of the many users there and a few elsewhere, it would appear that **no user has found a way to lock Camera Mode as enabled** or if they have, they never shared it. From this, it seems probable that there is no way to do it on console. PC versions with modding might be able to find a way around the problem, but for the XBOX 360 version, it would seem you're out of luck.

Comment: I would like to provide a more authoritative answer but it can be quite challenging to prove that you cannot do something within a realm of unrestricted possibility and without any official word, it's hard to assume any kind of authority.